# Is there any way to calculate effect size between a pre-test and a post-test when scores on pre-test is 0 (or almost 0)

Tags: r, statistics, data-analysis

I would like to calculate an effect size between scores from pre-test and post-test of my studies.

However, due to the nature of my research, pre-test scores are usually 0 or almost 0 (before the treatment, participants usually do not have any knowledge in question).

I cannot just use Cohen's d to calculate effect sizes since the pre-test scores do not follow a normal distribution.

Is there any way I can calculate effect sizes in this case?

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for *Cohen's d* to see if the difference between the two time points (pre- and post-treatment) is large or small. The Cohen's d can be calculated as follows:

`(mean_post - mean_pre) / {(variance_post + variance_pre)/2}^0.5`

Where `variance_post` and `variance_pre` are the sample variances. Nowhere does it require here that the pre- and post-treatment score are normally distributed.

There are multiple packages available in R that provide a function for Cohen's d: `effsize`, `pwr` and `lsr`. In `lsr` your R-code would look like this:

```
library(lsr)
cohensD(pre_test_vector, post_test_vector)
```

Sidenote: The average scores tend to a normal distribution when your sample size tends to infinity. As long as your sample size is large enough, the average scores follow a normal distribution ([Central Limit Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Central_limit_theorem)).

Comment: Thank you very much, Ken! I see, so we really do NOT need to conform that both pre-test and post-test scores are normally distributed. And thank you for suggesting lsr package. This package is nice.

As following your instruction, I stimulated calculation of an effect size;
pretest = c(0,0,0,0,0,0,0)
posttest = c(5,3,3,4,1,2,3)
cohensD(pretest, posttest)

Cohen's d = 3.286... 
I feel this is way larger than Cohen's guideline (0.2 is small, 0.5 is medium, and 0.8 is large; Cohen, 1992). Do you think it is valid for me to use this effect size to compare with other studies? Thank you,

Comment: I'm not completely sure about the normality part! I have seen posts. here is a paper that explicitly deals with non-normal data that is not homogenous: https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/26487051

Comment: Oh, this paper is nice! I'll read this. Thank you very much, Ken. :)